# How to execute php files with crontab in linode

Tags: php, cron, linode

I am trying to execute a php file hosted on linode with crontab.

Here's what i've done so far.

i added a line to :

```
/etc/crontab ('crontab -e' is used too)
```

And I want to execute this file every 2 mins.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/path/to/my/php/file.php
```

Here's the code in my php file for testing

```
// Set error reporting
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'On');
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On');

$fh = fopen('gallery.xml', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
fclose($fh);
```

Both the php file and xml file are with 777 permission.
If I open the php file directly in the browser, the xml file can record the variable.
But nothing happen when I used the crontab. It seems that it didn't work for me.

I am using Linode and debian 6.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please give some suggestion. Thanks.

Bryant

Comment: Is there a `/usr/bin/php` on your server? It might be installed elsewhere.

Comment: To what Waleed is saying... if you run `/usr/bin/php /srv/www/path/to/my/php/file.php` at prompt what happens?

Comment: Yes, I use 'which php' to get the path.

Comment: If things still do not work with the advice give you should modify your crontab entry to output stout and sterr to a file so you can see if any errors are occurring.  You should also check /var/log/cron to see if there are any obvious entries relating to your cron job.

Comment: @Lipongo Thank you. I changed the xml file path to an absolute one and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to correctly set your working directory or use absolute paths for your `fopen()` as cron's default working directory is the home directory of whatever account the job's running under, so it may be `~/root` or `~/yourusername` (see [this stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job) too). You may try this:

```
*/2 * * * * ( cd /srv/www/path/to/my/php/ ; /usr/bin/php -q file.php )
```

or this:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /srv/www/path/to/my/php/ && /usr/bin/php -q file.php
```

and the difference is that 2nd one will not fire PHP if `cd` failed which is perfectly what we want as if `cd` failed there will be no `file.php` to launch.

You can also set executable bit (i.e. `chmod a+x file.php`) and add this as very first line to your script:

```
# /usr/bin/php -q
```

so you'd be able to invoke your script as any other app or script (i.e. `./file.php`). then your crontab entry would look:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /srv/www/path/to/my/php/ && ./file.php
```

And do not use cryptic "-1" in your `error_reporting()`. It tells nothing. Use `E_ALL` or anything that ends in valid setting and is more self explanatory than -1.

Comment: +1. this'll be it - need an absolute path on the file being written, because cron's default working directory is the home directory of whatever account the job's running under. Most likely that's NOT where the op wants the file.

Comment: Hi, @WebnetMobile.com,thank you for your answer. I change the path to an absolute one and it works now! Thank you!